# Black holes and trapped region

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

When we talk about in case of Schwarzschild of the trapped region, so the region $r<2m$, so the region where the gravity, that in some sense represents by a physical point of view the curvature of spacetime, is so high that whatever light signals is destined to crush at $r=0$, without crossing it.

> When we talk about Schwarzschild black hole I have understood that this is another name of the trapped region, I am right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's analyze the structure of a [Schwarzschild black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric) (i.e. non-rotating and not electrically charged).

### The black hole

It is often not entirely clear what is included to be the black hole. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) describes it as

> a region of spacetime where gravity is so strong that nothing — no particles or even electromagnetic radiation such as light — can escape from it

while the [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/starsgalaxies/black_hole_description.html) definition is

> an astronomical object with a gravitational pull so strong that nothing, not even light, can escape it

These two definitions may seem very similar, but there is a distinction: Wikipedia defines a black hole as the *region* of spacetime where the curvature is strong enough to prevent light from escaping, while in the NASA definition, a black hole is described as the *object* which exerts this gravitational pull.
As you will see later, the first definition describes the "interior" of the black hole.

### The event horizon

The event horizon of a black hole can, depending on the definition, be seen as the "surface" of a black hole: It is the region where the curvature of spacetimes becomes so strong that even light cannot escape. More technical, the event horizon is the region where the escape velocity equals the speed of light.
The radius of the event horizon is called the Schwarzschild radius and depends, for a Schwarzschild black hole, only on the mass. It is mathematically described by $$r_s=\frac{2GM}{c^2}$$ or, if one chooses units where $G$ and $c$ are one, this becomes $r_s=2M$.

### The "interior"

The event horizon is the surface of a sphere with $r_s$ as radius. This sphere seems to be what you are describing since everything inside can never escape - the escape velocity is greater than $c$.
This region is also what is sometimes (see the Wikipedia definition, for example) described as the black hole.

### The singularity

At the center of a black hole is predicted to be a gravitational singularity. This is a point-like "region" of spacetime where the curvature becomes infinite. This however means that General relativity cannot describe a singularity.

Comment: The radius of the horizon does not have a unique definition. For example, it his original solution, Karl Schwarzschild set this radius to zero: $$r_s\equiv\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=0$$ See: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9905030 (he uses $\alpha$ to denote $r_s$). What you are describing as "radius" is a *reduced circumference* (the circumference divided by $2\pi$). In curved spacerimes, a sphere with a finite area and circumference may have a zero volume (such as inside the Schwarzschild horizon, as observed from outside, see the end of the section 3 on page 6 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.1734).

Comment: @safesphere Thank you for commenting. As I am only a high school student, I am not sure if I will understand it, but I will later read through your links and then try to edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of names for this region, but the most common in the literature is "the black hole interior"

Comment: So trapped region is another name to talk about black hole? What I have not understood is: it is right to think by a mathematical point of view to the black hole as the region $r<2m$?

Comment: That's it's whole own thing, too.  If you cornered me and said "what is a black hole", I'd probably say that the *whole spacetime* is the black hole, and if you double-cornered, me, I'd probably say that the horizon is the essential bit of the spacetime, and would not worry about the interior region

Comment: Sorry I have not understood, surely it is my fail since I am not so confident with these notion. What you wanto to say is that the black hole is a region hidden inside the trapped region but it does not coincide with it?

Comment: @cely: the entire black hole solution, aside from the singularity itself (which, in the case of schwarzschild, is spacelike, is more a "point in time" than a "place") is vacuum, so it's hard to talk about where something "is".  The true essential feature of the solution that makes it a black hole is the horizon, so most physicists usually call the horizon as the "feature" that makes a spacetime one that contains the black hole, and avoid directly discussing the interior as much as they can.

Comment: We can say that it is black hole what is over the event horizon?

Comment: @cely What is a magnet? Is it what is inside of it (where you can't easily get)? Is it its magnetic field outside of it? Or is it its surface, to which everything sticks? Or is it all of the above? Once you answer these questions, you'll know the answer to you own question.

Answer (score 0):

Trapped region is a region bounded by the last light-ray that could escape from the gravitational collapse to a black hole. Think about Schwarzschild BH for instance. If you are within the region r < 2M, then once the critical mass is achieved and the BH is formed, you cannot escape. However, if you are just outside the r=2M, then you can escape. r=2M is the bound.

Comment: So the blackhole is inside $r<2m$?

Comment: black hole is not inside $r < 2m$. Black hole is the spacetime itself, but the singularity is within the $r<2m$ region, which is behind the horizon at $r=2m$.